# Show that $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |p(z)| = \infty$ for a non-constant polynomial $p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function. By definition we have $\lim_{|z|} |f(z)| = \infty$ when for every $M \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists some $R > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \geq M$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| \geq R$. Assume that $p$ is a non-constant polynomial, show that $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |p(z)| = \infty$.

I have trouble understanding this question, and thus I have no idea where to start/how to approach it.

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Write $|p(z)|=|a_nz^n+\dots+a_0|=|z^n(a_n+a_{n-1}/z+\dots+a_0/z^n)|$.  The expression in parentheses goes to $a_n$.  So, $\lim_{z\to\infty}|p(z)|=\lim_{z\to\infty}|a_nz^n|=\infty$.